# HTTP response 403 when trying to push to registry

Tags: docker

I am using Docker 1.8.0.

I am trying to push my first image to the hub, but I keep on getting a 403 response when doing it:

```
$ docker login
  Username (myuser):
$ docker push myuser/myimage
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/myuser/myimage] (len: 1)
2a720e713044: Buffering to Disk 
Error parsing HTTP response: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>\nRequest forbidden by administrative rules.\n</body></html>\n\n"
```

I am logging in before doing it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you done `docker login` first to set up your credentials?

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot to mention it in the original post.

Comment: Is the password that is stored in the auth field in ~/.docker/config.json the correct one? Sorry if this is all a bit obvious but there isn't much to go on.

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes - the password is encrypted. When I do `docker login` it does say that the authentication is successful...

Comment: It's not actually encrypted it's only base-64 encoded so you can check it easily by doing a base-64 decode. However, if you are successfully logging in then it must be valid.

I'm not in a place where I can try anything out yet but I'll have a think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded my Docker installation to 1.8.1 from 1.8.0 and it now works.

On Ubuntu, that would be `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade docker-engine`.